# Page redirect using the javascript "Form" method

Tags: javascript

I set up a page redirect using javascript, and the "Form" method from the following website:

[https://webworkshop.net/auto-redirecting_methods](https://webworkshop.net/auto-redirecting-methods-examples/)

I set this up a few weeks ago, and it worked fine then. However, when I looked at it the other day it was no longer working.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Please provide the could You are currently having the issue with.

Comment: Sorry, here's the code I used:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript"><!--document.myform.submit()//-->
    <script>
     <title>Main Page</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>This page has a hidden form</p>
    <form name="myform" action="destination" method="get"></form>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're simply wanting to redirect:

You can do it with JavaScript and HTML Meta tags

```html
<!doctype>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/new-page.html">
</head>

<body>
  Auto refresh in 0 seconds
</body>

</html>
```

**The other method is by using JavaScript, like below:**

```html
<!doctype>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    window.location = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/new-page.html';
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  This would also redirect as soon as the page loads.
</body>

</html>
```

Hope that helps